# Git not letting me checkout another branch

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, github

I recently had issued with pushing sensitive information up to git.  I removed the sensitive information from my config/secrets.yml on github and then used git update-index --assume-unchanged config/secrets.yml so the file won't be tracked and pushed to github.  Now, when I try to switch to my local master branch I get

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>       config/secrets.yml
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>   Aborting

Git status says

> nothing to commit, working directory clean

and there are no changes to stash.

How can I fix this issue?

How can I make sure github has a bare bones secrets.yml file so Heroku can see the secret keys while still being able to add future development and test secrets.

I don't want to push up the new secrets and I do not want to pull down the bare bones secrets.yml file from github.

Comment: The message recommends `git stash`.  Did you try that?

Comment: I recommend you to add **config/secrets.yml** to your **.gitignore** so it won't be tracked. Then you can revert git update-index